# Iteration warping image?

Tags: image-processing, opencv

I would like to do somethings like this [Image Warping LIB](http://code.google.com/p/imgwarp-opencv/). Image should be deformed (warping) as the control points, however, as I try using OpenCV-based its possible to deforming from original image to deformed image. But, cannot use that result (deformed image) as the source image for deform in the next stage.

To do the stage-by-stage deformation (use the previous deformed image as the source image for each state), can I do this? Since, the interpolation make the image blur and become black or white when doing some iteration.

Thank you for help!

[image: Original Image][image: Deformed Image]

Comment: Hi,did you have build it on c++, then please share code to me i can not run on c++ while it is working fine on QT

Comment: @Sameer Z. did you still need my code?

Answer (score 2):

The technical solution is not to just apply the deformation after each stage, but to aggregate the deformations and apply the total deformation on the source image. For example in the first stage your movement of the control points defines a deformation. The deformation is saved to a stack and applied. You move a new set of control points. The additional deformation is saved to the stack as well. But instead of applying the deformation on the already deformed information, you compute the total deformation and apply that on the original image. That way the rounding and interpolation is only done once no matter how many stages you have.

That said, computing the total deformation out of two consecutive deformations may be very easy or very hard depending on what those deformations do and how that is implemented. The source code of that library did not look promising for an easy solution.